# How to send file data via curl to another server in $_FILES

Tags: php, file, file-upload, curl

I have two servers one is application server while another one is API server, API server reads data from `$_FILES`.

So my question is how can I send the File data to API Server so that it can get data in `$_FILES`?

I need CURL to do that, no form post.

Thanks,

WA

Comment: You should read this here first: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
There is explanation on how to send files with curl.
If you are done with that, get back here and show us how you did it.

Comment: yeah thanks I saw, let me try if $_FILES works

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir, curl request work with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. not $_FILE

Comment: Yeah thanks it is working, I wasn't aware with @ file uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [php.net](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
<?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script to send a file with php/cURL via POST:

```
<?php
$target_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/accept.php';
    //This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
    /*  the at sign '@' is required before the
     * file name.
     */
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
```

And here is the corresponding script to accept the file.

```
 <?php
$uploaddir = realpath('./') . '/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file_contents']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_contents']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
?>
```