# How to move a php file from server to server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing a Wordpress plugin that once you activate the plugin I want to 
copy some templates from a external repo(server)
to the downloads folder in the current wordpress instance.

What I have done so far is this which works fine but
the problem is that is trying to execute the php code functions inside,
I am getting this erro fomr the error log :

> [26-Sep-2014 00:11:47 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_the_title() in /home/german/public_html/wp-content/uploads/template/squeeze-land.php on line 21

So is trying to execute the `get_the_titel()` function

> > I'd like to move a file to a target folder in another server.
> >     thank you.

```
function getTemplates(){

       $url = 'http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/template/squeeze-land.php';
       $newFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/uploads/template/testing.php';

        set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time

        $path = $newFile;
        $url = $url;
        $newfname = $path;
        echo 'Starting Download!<br>';
        $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
        if($file) {
            $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
            if($newf)
                while(!feof($file)) {
                    fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
                    echo '1 MB File Chunk Written!<br>';
                }
        }
        if($file) {
            fclose($file);
        }
        if($newf) {
            fclose($newf);
        }
        echo 'Finished!';
}
```

Comment: is the file public ? can you get it with a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "CURL" to copy the templates from other server to your server... This will help you more...

Hope so this link will help you as well..

[How to send file data via curl to another server in $_FILES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819454/how-to-send-file-data-via-curl-to-another-server-in-files)

Comment: Hi, I tried CURl and I have the same problem, is executing the php file. SO far I had to change the file extention  to .txt so doesn't interpretate the php.
But still is just a provisional solution.